# Feed Me Cron Job failing on 123-reg hosting

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to set up a cron job to run the feed me direct feed url in 123-reg hosting. The command they are saying to use is:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/index.php?p=actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task&direct=1&feedId=1&passkey=xxxxxxx
```

However I'm getting an error:

Could not open input file: /home/username/public_html/index.php?p=actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task

The feed action runs fine when used in a url. So is there something not right with the cron? Looking at the error message that is sent through it seems to be stripping anything after the first & ?

Comment: The error message states that the index.php cannot be found. You can double check the scripts correct path just to be sure using `echo __DIR__;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a bit of digging. It turns out I was able to run this with wget. But had to comment out the &'s as these were being read as commands in cron. Also worth noting you would need to do the same with %'s as well.

So the final solution is:

```
wget -q -O - https://domain/index.php?p=actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task\&direct=1\&feedId=1\&passkey=xxxxxxxxxx >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.